# Equivalence of characterizations of the convolution of Borel measures

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

This comes from Lang's $\textit{Real and Functional Analysis}$.

> Let $M$ be the set of all positive Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^p$. Define convolution $\ast:M\times M\rightarrow M$ by $$(\mu\ast\nu)(A)=(\mu\otimes\nu)(\sigma^{-1}(A))$$ where $\otimes$ denote product measure taken in the usual sense, and $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^p\times\mathbb{R}^p\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$ is addition. Show that $\mu\ast\nu$ is the unique positive Borel measure $\tau$ so that for each function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^p$ which is step with respect to rectangles one has $$\int f\,d\tau=\int\int f(x+y)\,d\nu(y)\,d\mu(x)$$

After consulting the literature, I find that the convolution of Borel measures is usually done in reverse, and I haven't been able to track down a proof of the equivalence of the characterizations. In my own attempts to show it, I have found it tricky to show the connection between the inverse of the addition map and the sets associated to the characteristic function expansion of $f$. Something tells me I'm missing a detail or two here conceptually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\chi_A(x+y)=\chi_{\sigma^{-1}(A)}(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was scratching my head knowing I was missing something obvious and this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Define the measure $\mu * \nu$ by $(\mu * \nu)(E) = (\mu \otimes \nu)(\sigma^{-1}(E))$.  By definition,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{p}} f(x) (\mu * \nu)(dx) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2p}} f(\sigma(x,y)) \mu(dx) \nu(dy) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{p}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{p}} f(x + y) \mu (dx) \nu(dy)
\end{align*}
This certainly works if $f \geq 0$; otherwise, if $|f|$ is $\mu * \nu$-integrable, apply Fubini's Theorem.